# Why do polarizable nucleophiles favor SN2 over E2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

Weakly basic ions and polarizable bases favor $\mathrm{S_{N}2}$ over $\mathrm{E2}$. Why? The argument used that polarizable nucleophiles form bonds earlier, stabilizing the transition state, can be applied to either $\mathrm{S_{N}2}$ or $\mathrm{E2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Polarisable Nucleophiles increase the rate of an S<sub>n</sub>2-type reaction but not an E2 reaction because the more polarisable a base is, lower the electronegativity and charge density (conversely, higher ionic radius) it has.

Now, we know that the basic strength depends on these factors( in a period, we check the electronegativity and in a group, the ionic radius).

As, the Rate Determining Step of an E2 reaction involves the attack of a base, lower basic strength would mean that the reaction would be slower. Hence, more polatisable bases means that E2 would be slower.

Comment: But why doesn't the stronger bonding in the TS for E2 that would result from using a more polarizable nucleophile matter

Comment: the base is only used for removing H+ ion from the carbon in the rds.